# How to make AWS IoT Rule to split agregated data before sending then to Timestream

Tags: aws-iot, amazon-timestream

integrating exiting IoT Rule based solution with new AWS Timestream feature I came across issue, that IoT Topic messages send are aggregated. This is not integrating well with Timestream DB, as it accepts data send as single measurements.

There is possible to put some SQL code into IoT Rule Action, but I think it is limited to handle only single measurement messages. Is my assumption true?

I don't think changing code on edge devices to go back to send single measurements only is an option. What would be recommended to tackle the issue on AWS side?

Answer (score 0):

If your `Dimensions` stay constant, than a single rule is all you need. EVERY attribute you `SELECT` in the rule will be a `measurement`. So multi-measurement writes ARE supported. The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/timestream-rule-action.html) also has exactly this example.